# Can't download data via appcfg.py. "Application Default Credentials are not available" error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-oauth

This has worked for years.  Today is not working.

Running `appcfg.py download_data --flags...`, and cannot get properly authorized.

Ran `gcloud auth login`

and got back:

```
Saved Application Default Credentials.

You are now logged in as [correct@gmail.com].
Your current project is [correct].
```

but when I run `appcfg.py download_data ...` I get this error:

```
raise ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError(ADC_HELP_MSG)
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The
Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if
running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
defining the credentials. See
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default
credentials for more information.
```

I updated the Google Cloud SDK, and now get a different error:

```
client.py:539 Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token 
client.py:797 Refreshing access_token 

Error 302: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

I have also set the credentials in Terminal:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "https://www.myurl/credentials.json"
set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES 1
gcloud config set project "correct_project_name"
```

I have also tried setting the env_variable flag in the appcfg command:

```
--env_variable=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:"https://www.myurl/credentials.json"
```

Seems to be a GAE bug. Removing the login:admin from the remote_api handler in app.yaml fixes it in production, but not local dev server. The 302 was telling me that the app was trying to redirect, perhaps to a Google login page. Was never seeing the prompt asking for email and password.

```
handlers: 
- url: /remote_api
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
  #login: admin  <-- removing admin fixes it in production
  secure: always
```

On the dev server, removing the admin login yields this:

```
client.py:797 Refreshing access_token 
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.
--- end server output ---
```

Did Google change something in the --oauth2 workflow?  I appear to be authorized, but the download crashes at the auth step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.9.27, where it does not allow a login prompt.  When reverting back to 1.9.26, it works.  Interestingly, my gcloud components still have the 1.9.27 version:

```
>$ gcloud version

Google Cloud SDK 0.9.83

alpha 2015.10.08
app 2015.10.16
app-engine-python 1.9.27
beta 2015.10.08
core 2015.10.16
core-nix 2015.09.03
gcloud 2015.10.16
```

temporary solution:  go to https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/ to get version 1.9.26

Submitted bug report:  https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=340